# Reading application settings best practice

Tags: c++, qt, qsettings

In my desktop app I use QSettings to persist various application values.  For example, main form position, recent documents, connection paramenters and some things that alter the way the application behaves, for example "don't show this message again" on information dialogs.

My usual way of handling this is to read all the settings into a struct or object when the application starts and save them when the application closes.

I also have a dialog that enables me to edit many of the values in the settings object and have them saved when the dialog is closed.

Values in the settings object will be needed by many windows and maybe non-visual objects..

What is the best way to do this?

I have started by having the settings object as a member of the main window, but then I have the problem of other windows needing to have access to the main window's members.

I did think I could have the settings object created within its own cpp file and just #include that where needed.  But I'm not sure if this possible or the syntax of it.

What is best practice for this scenario?

Comment: why is other windows accessing the main windows members a problem?

Comment: Use singleton pattern for your settings object

Comment: @tobi30 doing that breaks encapsulation principles for starters, so is not best practice.

Comment: @Zlatomir I was thinking along those lines.  Will a singleton object be able to be created in its own code files (if you see what I mean)?

Comment: @MichaelVincent Sorry, but I dont see how a mainwindow providing a `getProperties()` method would break any encapsulation...

Comment: @tobi303 probably because you must pass the mainwindow object around in order to access it's properties.

Comment: @Miki Not if he makes the getter/setter static. But anyhow I am not sure if passing the mainwindow object around would be too bad. I am newbie to qt, isnt the mainwindow anyway accessible from anywhere?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest to use always the [QSettings](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html), avoiding the supplementary struct or class. You can set *application name*, *organization name*, and *organization domanin* in your main.

From QtDocs:

> If you use QSettings from many places in your application, you might want to specify the organization name and the application name using QCoreApplication::setOrganizationName() and QCoreApplication::setApplicationName(), and then use the default QSettings constructor:

```
QCoreApplication::setOrganizationName("MySoft");
QCoreApplication::setOrganizationDomain("mysoft.com");
QCoreApplication::setApplicationName("Star Runner");
```

And then use the default constructor where you need to acceess the properties:

```
QSettings settings;
```

> QSettings objects can be created either on the stack or on the heap (i.e. using new). Constructing and destroying a QSettings object is very fast.

You can set a setting wherever in the program:

> If there already exists a setting with the same key, the existing value is overwritten by the new value. For efficiency, the changes may not be saved to permanent storage immediately. (You can always call sync() to commit your changes.)

You can also use it in different threads without problems:

> QSettings is reentrant. This means that you can use distinct QSettings object in different threads simultaneously. This guarantee stands even when the QSettings objects refer to the same files on disk (or to the same entries in the system registry). If a setting is modified through one QSettings object, the change will immediately be visible in any other QSettings objects that operate on the same location and that live in the same process.
>
> QSettings can safely be used from different processes (which can be different instances of your application running at the same time or different applications altogether) to read and write to the same system locations. It uses advisory file locking and a smart merging algorithm to ensure data integrity. Note that sync() imports changes made by other processes (in addition to writing the changes from this QSettings).

Comment: Thank you for your comments and answer @Miki  I am going to go with this method.

Answer (score 6):

QSettings is not thread safe. The documentation says it clearly:

> QSettings is reentrant. This means that you can use distinct QSettings
>   object in different threads simultaneously. This guarantee stands even
>   when the QSettings objects refer to the same files on disk (or to the
>   same entries in the system registry).

It is reentrant but not thread safe. You can not safely use a global QSettings object from multiple threads. If a thread calls beginGroup() and then a second thread also calls beginGroup() then you have a problem because your QSettings object has the wrong prefix.

It is thread safe to use multiple QSettings objects for the same file. So you should create QSettings objects locally on the stack instead of sharing a single object globally to avoid race conditions.

Answer (score 1):

I fail to see the problem.

There are two basic options:

1. Create an object once and pass it to all windows:
   For the sake of simplicity let's assume that your settings object is of type Qsettings. Also let's assume that your application is not multi-threaded. 
   You create this object int your main function and pass it as a parameter to every window you create. All windows will `#include <QSettings>` and know how to access it. The same goes if you have your own settings class. The interface is in it's own header and the implementation in it's own cpp. You create it one and pass it to all windows.
2. As mentioned in the comments You can also use a singelton. Just crate a static function for the settings class that returns the same instance that was declared static inside the function.
   like thus:

```
class Settings
{
public:
    static Settings & TheSettings()
    {
        static Settings theSettings_;
        return theSettings_;
    }
    // Here go all methods for accessing the data
    // You will also want:
    ~Settings();
    Settings(const Settings &);
    Settings & operator=(const Settings &);
    // If you are using c++11 you may also want to add move constructor and assignment. 
    // Or you can just use the defaults for all the above if all your private members can destruct themselves  
private:
    Settings();
};
```

Here is the above with QSettings as the settings object:

```
class Settings
{
public:
    static QSettings & TheSettings()
    {
        static QSettings theSettings_;
        return theSettings_;
    }

private:
    Settings();
    Settings(const Settings &);
    Settings & operator=(const Settigns &);
};
```

Hope this puts you on the right track

**PS.** For multithreaded apps make sure all internal data inside your Settings object is accessed inside a critical section (or mutex protection)

**PPS.** Please note as Miki mentioned in the comments that QSettings is thread safe so you don't have to wrap access to it in a critical section. However if you are ever to use a different underlying storage (Be it a file, another container) it will probably be necessary.

Comment: 1) why using a std::map when you could use a QVariantMap? 2) Why reimplementing with a lot of effort the same thing as QSettings?

Comment: It was just a sample for the principle but I fixed it to use Qsettings

Comment: Yeah, I understand that. But still my question: QSettings is already thread safe, you can have multiple instances without problems, etc... Why you need something more than QSettings?

Comment: @Miki You don't need anything else when you use Qt. However if you want to have access to it from anywhere in the application you need to understand the principle of how to do it. the OP obviously does not. My answer is designed to help any one wishing to implement such a scheme regardless of the underlying storage object, Hence all the options. But I will EDIT my answer to point the QSettings is thread safe

Comment: For a non-Qt environtment your design is (in my opinion) the right choice, as soon as you remove all Qt-related stuff. I'll vote up if you make it clear.

Comment: @Miki I hope you can vote it up with my new EDIT - have alook :-)

Comment: @SebastianCabot thank you for your answer and comments.  I'm going to go with Miki's answer as this is a Qt project.

Comment: @MichaelVincent. Thank you. However you will discover that just saying "use QSettings" which you already use will not help use it through your entire application. That is why I took the trouble of writing this answer. Best of luck.

Comment: @SebastianCabot  I suspect that there are some subtleties that I don't yet appreciate about your solution.  I'll take another look when I'm more familiar with Qt and C++.  Thanks again for your answer.